# Hide a li if div is empty?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hide, is-empty

I've looked around for about a week or so now trying various techniques but so far no luck.

I am using javascript based tabs to tab out content on a page. The content is dynamically generated from Wordpress custom fields. If the div has no content to display in the HTML I would like that corresponding tab to not appear. Is this possible?

my code is as such:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="tab1"><a href="#view1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li class="tab2"><a href="#view2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li class="tab3"><a href="#view3">Tab 3</a></li>

<div class="tabcontents">

<div id="view1">

<div class="noScreen">
<h2>Tab 1</h2>
</div>

<div class="view1">
<?php the_field('tab1'); ?>
</div>

</div>
<!--end Tab1-->

<div id="view2">

<div class="noScreen">
<h2>Tab 2</h2>
</div>

<div class="view2">
<?php the_field('tab2'); ?>
</div>

</div>
<!--end Tab2-->

<div id="view3">

<div class="noScreen">
<h2>Tab 3</h2>
</div>

<div class="view3">
<?php the_field('tab3'); ?>
</div>

</div>
<!--end Tab1-->

</div>
<!--end tabcontents-->
```

So if Tab1 and Tab3 respond back with data from the post but Tab 2 is empty I would like to hide the li for Tab 2 up above.

Can anyone help?

thank you in advance

Comment: It appears that the php function is causing issues even with now using a get_field to check for the value before displaying.

Comment: I'm not sure how to but you may mark this resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to fix some missing tags and quotes from your HTML above, but this seems to do the trick.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q27K6/

```
$(function(){
    $('div.tabcontents > div').each(function(index){
        var innerView = $(this).find('div[class^="view"]');
        var innerHtml = $(innerView).html();
        if(innerHtml.trim() == ''){
            $(this).hide();
            $('ul.tabs').find('li').eq(index).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the missing quotes. I wrote this at the end of the day on friday. When I add this JS into my site nothing seems to happen oddly enough.

Comment: @svsdnb Do you see any errors or anything once the page loads? If you view your page's source does your HTML match what you have in your question?

Comment: Should I put this JS towards the bottom of the page? Maybe it's running it prior to php outputting the HTML which is why it's showing up since there's the php function call in there. ?

Comment: No errors and yes the HTML matches. I double checked it just to make sure I didn't fudge that up.

Comment: @svsdnb Try putting an `alert('test');` inside the `each` function just to make sure it's getting hit. It's all wrapped inside `$(function(){...});` so it should be waiting for the page to load before running, unless the php is running async or something.

Comment: I added alert('test'); with no change

Comment: Also I was able to get this to work using a copy of my exact code but once the PHP is introduced it stops working. 
http://jsfiddle.net/MikeRS/Zq7e7/3/

Comment: Finally got this to work for me. The PHP was using a javascript so I just had to put this javascript in the footer. Works like a champ! Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `the_field` (which *prints* info) see if theres a `get_field` function that *returns* info. That way you could decide beforehand if the div will be empty.

```
$tab2content=get_field('tab2');
if(!empty($tab2content)) {
    echo '<div id="view2">';
    echo '<div class="noScreen"><h2>Tab 2</h2></div>';
    echo '<div class="view2">'.$tab2content.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

If that doesn't work, after your contents is loaded and any ajax calls are resolved,  you could tell if the div was empty by running

```
if(jQuery('.view2').html()==='') {
    jQuery('#view2').hide();
}
```

However, keep in mind that if your DOM has more than one elements with  `view2` class, the html() method will yield the contents of the first one that matches.

Comment: Unfortunately get_field didn't seem to resolve any data. The second one didn't seem to work either for some reason.

Comment: Can you try typing  ```jQuery('.view2').html()``` on the console?

Comment: typing into the console returned no value

Comment: Ok I was able to get the 2nd suggestion to work with a little change however it doesn't work once PHP is involved.
http://jsfiddle.net/MikeRS/b5V8f/27/

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if the contents of `<div class='view2'>` is empty? `div id='view2'>` will never be empty, so I'll assume it's the former.

So, whether it is empty or not depends on whether there is anything returned from the php function `the_field('tab2')`, right?

So, one way of solving the problem is to do it on the server, by checking if the function `the_field('tab2')` (or whatever) is empty. That's slightly convoluted in php though.

Or in javascript:

```
$().ready(function() {

  var hideTab = function(index) {
    var $view = $('.view' + index)
      , $tab = $('.tab' + index);
    if($.trim($view.html()).length === 0) {
      $tab.hide();
    }
  }

  // Stick this in a loop to make it neater
  hideTab(1);
  hideTab(2);
  hideTab(3);
});
```

Comment: Yes correct. Sorry for not being more direct. I'm looking to see if the div class of view is empty after the php return.